# Error in converting c++ union structure to c#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, unions

i have some complex structure in c++

```
typedef struct
  {
    long Length;
    short Type;
    union
    {
      MMTPConxReq ConxReq;
      MMTPConxAck ConxAck;
      MMTPConxNack ConxNack;
      MMTPErrInd ErrInd;
      MMTPDcnxReq DcnxReq;
      MMTPDcnxAck DcnxAck;
      MMTPDataMsg DataMsg;
      MMTPSyncAck SyncAck;
      MMTPStartReq StartReq;
      MMTPStartAck StartAck;
      MMTPStartNack StartNack;
      MMTPSrvcMsg SrvcMsg;
      MMTPDsptchMsg DsptchMsg;
      MMTPRcnxReq RcnxReq;
    } Data;
    Ticks TimeStamp;
  } MMTPMsg;

typedef struct
  {
    char SubsId[FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+1];
    int Level;
    char Options[FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS+1];
    char AuthData[FIELD_SIZE_AUTH_DATA+1];
  } MMTPConxReq;

  // Contents of CONX-ACK message.
  typedef struct
  {
    char Options[FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS+1];
  } MMTPConxAck;

 // Contents of DATA-MSG message.
  typedef struct
  {
    int SeqNb;
    int DataSize;
    MMTPAdminData AD;
    char Data[FIELD_SIZE_DATA+1];
  } MMTPDataMsg;

// Administrative data.
  typedef struct
  {
    int Type;
    int Size;
    union
    {
      MMTPAdminDataA1 A1;
      MMTPAdminDataA2 A2;
      MMTPAdminDataE0 E0;
      MMTPAdminDataE1 E1;
      MMTPAdminDataG0 G0;
      MMTPAdminDataM0 M0;
      MMTPAdminDataRR RR;
      MMTPAdminGeneric Generic;
    } Data;
    char Unknown[FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN];
  } MMTPAdminData;
```

in  conver to c# (step to step) i create this structs:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct MMTPMsg
    {
        public Int32 Length;
        public MessageType Type;
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10060)]
        //public fixed byte Data[10060];
        public MMTPMsgData Data;
        public Int64 TimeStamp;
    }

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]//,Size =10060)]
    internal struct MMTPMsgData
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MMTPConxReq ConxReq;//12+4+17+9
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MMTPConxAck ConxAck;//17
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //public MMTPConxNack ConxNack;//e
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //public MMTPErrInd ErrInd;//e+4+4+4+(9500+256+24+1)
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //public MMTPDcnxReq DcnxReq;//e+4
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //public MMTPDcnxAck DcnxAck;//4
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MMTPDataMsg DataMsg;//4+4+(4+4+()+256)+9501
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //public MMTPSyncAck SyncAck;
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //public MMTPStartReq StartReq;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MMTPStartAck StartAck;
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //public MMTPStartNack StartNack;
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //public MMTPSrvcMsg SrvcMsg;
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //public MMTPDsptchMsg DsptchMsg;
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //public MMTPRcnxReq RcnxReq;
    }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]//, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    unsafe internal struct MMTPConxReq
    {

        public fixed byte SubsId[Constants.FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID + 1];
        public int Level;

        public fixed byte Options[Constants.FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS + 1];

        public fixed byte AuthData[Constants.FIELD_SIZE_AUTH_DATA + 1];
    }

internal struct MMTPConxAck
    {
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = Constants.FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS + 1)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = Constants.FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS + 1)]
        public string Options;//[Constants.FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS + 1];

    }

 internal struct MMTPDataMsg
    {
        public int SeqNb;
        public int DataSize;
        public MMTPAdminData AD;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Constants.FIELD_SIZE_DATA + 1)]
        public byte[] Data;

    }
```

when run the c# app, i get this error

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'TestSle.MMTPMsgData' from assembly 'TestSle, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.'
```

if i comment 
this line from MMTPMsgData struct:

```
[FieldOffset(0)]
    public MMTPConxReq ConxReq;//12+4+17+9
```

no error happen but i need this data.
what is wrong
i can not understand problem
help me please

Comment: I think the sizes for the union are different for each structure type.  In c++ the union would be the largest size of the individual structures.  So in c# you have to do that manually by finding largest structure and then specifying size of MMTPMsgData.

Comment: similar to this: https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/20866859/marshal+unmanaged+structure+with+enum+member+to+c